# Удаление элемента из словаря во время того как по этому словарю идешь циклом

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

Есть словарь словарей и из вложенного словаря мне нужно удалять ключи в зависимости от их содержимого. Код в примере выдает у меня эксепшн, счетчик цикла сбивается после удаления. Собственно что лучше сделать, через цикл for попробовать или там так же ошибка будет или вообще создать клон словаря и из него удалять элементы?

```
private static void RemoveMinCount(Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> dataFromText)
    {
        foreach (var key in dataFromText)
        {
            var tempKey = key.Key;
            var tempValue = dataFromText[tempKey];
            int maxCount = 0;                
            maxCount = GetMaxCount(tempValue, maxCount);
            foreach (var innerKey in tempValue)
            {
                if (innerKey.Value < maxCount)
                    dataFromText[key.Key].Remove(innerKey.Key);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: На всякий случай надо спросить - а вам точно здесь именно словарь нужен?

Comment: Да, без словаря не получится, до этого блока словарь и после тоже.

Comment: Попробуй использовать LINQ: https://makolyte.com/csharp-change-a-dictionarys-values-in-a-foreach-loop/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно склонировать ключи, а не весь словарь, и названия переменных у вас странные, перемудрили.

```
foreach (var pair in dataFromText)
{
    var innerDict = pair.Value;
    int maxCount = GetMaxCount(innerDict, 0);
    foreach (var innerKey in innerDict.Keys.ToArray()) // копирование ключей в массив
    {
        if (innerDict[innerKey] < maxCount)
            innerDict.Remove(innerKey);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно ещё красиво сделать:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
class RemoveFromDictionary {
    static int GetMaxCount(Dictionary<string, int> d, int i) { return 5; }
    static void RemoveMinCount(Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> dataFromText) {
        foreach (var kvp in dataFromText) {
            int maxCount = GetMaxCount(kvp.Value, 0);
            foreach (string key in kvp.Value.Where(w => w.Value < maxCount).Select(s => s.Key).ToList())
                kvp.Value.Remove(key);
        }
    }
    static void Main() {
        var tempValue = new Dictionary<string, int> {
            { "cat", 3 }, { "dog", 8 }, { "hackee", 1 }, { "crocodile", 20 } };
        var dataFromText = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> { { "zulu", tempValue } };
        RemoveMinCount(dataFromText);
        foreach (var p in dataFromText["zulu"]) Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", p.Key, p.Value);
    }
}
```

--->

dog: 8

crocodile: 20

Возможно, это решение чуть менее производительно, чем другое.

А можно ещё и так:

```
static void RemoveMinCount(ref Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> dataFromText) {
    dataFromText = dataFromText.ToDictionary(k => k.Key
        , v => v.Value.Where(w => w.Value >= GetMaxCount(v.Value, 0))
            .ToDictionary(dk => dk.Key, dv => dv.Value));
}
...
RemoveMinCount(ref dataFromText);
```